# HTML E-mail Sig to work in Firefox (Image Related)

Tags: html, css, html-email, windows-live

Using Windows Live E-mail, I make a signature and save the file which gives me the following code.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY dir=ltr>
<DIV dir=ltr>
<DIV style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial'; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial'; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
<DIV dir=ltr>
<DIV style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial'; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV>
<HR>
</DIV>
<DIV><IMG 
style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 5px 20px 0px 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px" 
title=pufs_mail_logo border=0 alt=pufs_mail_logo align=left 
src="G:\Profile\PUFS\E-Mail\pufs_mail_logo.png" width=120 height=100></DIV>
<DIV><STRONG><EM>for Pak United Food Services Ltd.,</EM></STRONG></DIV>
<DIV>Tel : 0092 55 3885502</DIV>
<DIV>Fax : 0092 55 3885503</DIV>
<DIV>Web Site : <A href="http://www.pufs.org/">www.pufs.org/</A></DIV>
<DIV>E-Mail : <A href="mailto:info@pufs.org">info@pufs.org</A></DIV>
<DIV>Address : Al Shafi Market, G.T Road</DIV>
<DIV>Gujranwala, Ghakhhar, 52200 – Pakistan</DIV>
<HR>
</DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

It works fine in IE9 and GG but in FF the image does not display and the alt text is shown instead. Please note that I have changed some code. The before code given was:

```
DIV><IMG 
style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px 20px 0px 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px" 
title=pufs_mail_logo border=0 alt=pufs_mail_logo align=left 
src="cid:C7912B932AF345A9A29DC8E6F6BCAE8B@JawadPC" width=120 height=100></DIV>
```

Which I changed to

```
<DIV><IMG 
    style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 5px 20px 0px 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px" 
    title=pufs_mail_logo border=0 alt=pufs_mail_logo align=left 
    src="G:\Profile\PUFS\E-Mail\pufs_mail_logo.png" width=120 height=100></DIV>
```

Basically just changing the path to the image file.

I could use an absllute url, but that has some seceurity issues. How do I get this simple file to dsiplay the image. (DOCTYPE?)

Comment: Firebug shows "Failed to load given url"

Comment: http://email.about.com/od/windowsmailtips/qt/et_inline_image.htm

Comment: http://www.w7forums.com/no-images-live-mail-t3053.html

Comment: adding DOCTYPE does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature file should reside on a web server. You should be pointing to it using a fully-qualified URI: `http://....`

BTW - most web-based mail clients will rip off the HEAD and everything up to the BODY. Just use the HTML.

Comment: It may work on your local network, where there is a G:\ drive, but in the wild, probably not.

Comment: so my best bet would be is to use "src="http://www.pufs.org/images/pufs_mail_logo.png"?